# How to edit string at a line in file in linux

Tags: linux

I have file which contains text at line 30 which is:

```
Icon="\<some path which we do not know\icon.png"
```

I want to replace above with:

```
Icon="\home\user\Img\Icons\icon.png"
```

What is the best way to do it.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\\<some path which we do not know/\\home\\user\\Img\\Icons/' text.txt
```

Perl approach is more preferred than sed, because of Unix compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an editor to do this manually or if you prefer to do it non interactively, you can use a small shell pipeline and `sed`.

```
sed `3 s/big path/custom path/` input_file.txt
```

where `3` is the line number, `big path` is what you want to replace and `custom path` is what you to want to replace it with. `input_file.txt` is your input file. This will print the replaced file onto the screen which you can redirect into another file using the `>` operator.

As a concrete example, suppose I have this file (`input_file.txt`)

```
Header
Random test
/bad/path/to/some/directory/icon.png
/bad/path/to/some/directory/icon.png
Footer
```

Now I'm going to run my command like so.

```
cat input_file.txt | sed '4 s/\/bad\/path\/to\/some\/directory\//\/home\/noufal\//'
```

and I get

```
Header
Random test
/bad/path/to/some/directory/icon.png
/home/noufal/icon.png
Footer
```

Notice that it has changed only the 4th line. The extra `\` characters in the command are to escape the `/` character which has special meaning for `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vim to find and replace your strings http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace or use 'sed' command

Comment: In this case, I do not know the path. It could be anything, then how can I search for it. Also if possible can you give examples

Comment: also you can use regex string to find it

Comment: Thank you. But can you please give any examples. i am new to regex or sed

Comment: i am not sure in correct string but regex string something like that: "Icon=\[a-zA-z0-9]\icon.png"